# Bootstrap 3 affix. Cannot remove margin-top

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I cannot seem to find where the margin-top is coming from when using the affix plugin on my Navbar.

I have [a website here] that may make it easier to see.

[image]

Is this something in which I should be using Javascript? I'm not hugely advanced yet on that and so it could be I missed something to do with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a margin; instead `.affix` is being positioned 50px from the top of the viewport - just change `top` to 0 instead:

```
.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh i see the use of top instead of margin-top threw me off thanks!.